# nextjs with apollo taking forever to bundle in development

Tags: webpack, babeljs, next.js, apollo-server, server-configuration

I am facing this issue in development, while working in **Nextjs** (on 9.4.4) with **Apollo Micro Server**  (on 2.14.1) as backend and **Apollo Client** (on 2.6.10) on client side. Everything works fine at times and on some occasions server takes forever to bundle files for hot module reload (some times up-to 30-45 minutes). I've tried to find the solutions online or at their repository but nothing seems to work.
currently my next.config.js looks like

```
const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css');

module.exports = withCSS({
  serverRuntimeConfig: {
    JWT_SECRET: 'changeme',
    MONGO_DB_URL: "mongodb://localhost:27017/example"
  },
  plugins: ['styled-jsx/babel'],
  webpackDevMiddleware: (config) => {
    config.watchOptions = {
      poll: 800,
      aggregateTimeout: 300,
    };
    return config;
  },
  webpack: function (config) {
        config.module.rules.push({
          test: /\.(eot|woff|woff2|ttf|svg|png|jpg|gif)$/,
          use: {
            loader: 'url-loader',
            options: {
              limit: 100000,
              name: '[name].[ext]'
            }
          }
        })
    return config;
  },
});
```

[image]

apart from server i am facing an other quite odd situation where **CSS** does not gets applied to the page and does not show an error either.